# Can I use “both” and “each” together in a sentence?

Tags: oxymoron

A has one house, and B has one house.

Is

> Both of them have one house each.

Grammatically correct?

I think it’s incorrect because it can be converted into ‘They have one house for each and for both’, which seems to be an oxymoron.

Comment: It's a tautology and sounds bad, perhaps even ungrammatical. To be avoided. // The default definition of 'oxymoron' is _not_ 'a contradiction in terms stated in few words' but 'what appears on the surface to be a contradiction in terms stated in few words, but actually makes sense on closer inspection'.

Comment: I don't have any real problem with it. And there are quite a few written instances of [***both have one each***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22both+have+one+each%22) in Google Books, so I'm obviously not alone in my "tolerance" here.

Comment: It sounds tautologous but there might be a case where you want to emphasise that you're talking about two people. It possibly makes more sense with "all of them" - X: "This is Alice, Bill and Colin." Y: "Do Alice and Bill have one house each?" X: "All of them have one house each." In contrast, Y: "Do all of them have one house each?" (X points to Alice and Bill) X: "Both of them have one house each. Colin doesn't have a house."

Comment: Perhaps not so much wrong as unnecessary. "They both have one house" -> has the possible reading that they share a house. "They have one house each" -> has one clear meaning. "Both" is no longer needed. But I could still imagine a contrived scenario that makes it appropriate: "Alice and Bill are distinguished from other billionaires by a common trait: they both have only one house each."